# \usepackage{opcit}: language and commenting

Tags: citing

I am writing in German, and we need some kind of "see" before some references in the footnote. (I'm new to footnote-citing). Also, I use overleaf, so maybe this is also a problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{opcit}
```

\renewcommand \idemtext {Ebenda.}

The usual solutions in square brackets do not work with this package. There is also an error when I try this, I'm not sure what does it mean:
[image: used LaTeX code with an error]

And this is what it looks like (I used vspace to bring it together for the screenshot):
[image: broken preview]

Also, for example "and" or "eds." is not translated automatically. Do you have any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 

Your question is not so clear. What is the problem and what is the question ?
I also suggest you to write a complete example, so we can run it and try to understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: The `opcit` package is quite old (last updated in 2006, so 14 years ago). I'm not sure it supports both prenotes and postnotes (i.e., `\cite[pre][post]{citekey}`), the examples in the manual are only with one type of note. Do you have a reason for using this package? There are also other packages that support footnote citations, most notably `biblatex`.

Comment: @Marijn: Write up some comprehensive answer as a Christmas gift. ;)

Answer (score 2):

As [Marijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn) [says in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576157/usepackageopcit-language-and-commenting#comment1450736_576157), the `opcit` documentation only ever uses `\cite` with a single optional argument (one for page numbers etc. after the citation, a postnote argument).

A look at the source code of the package indeed shows that it does not support two optional arguments to `\cite`. So with your current setup, it won't be easy to get the "See" in front of a citation.

As also mentioned in Marijn's comment, the `opcit` package was last updated in 2006 and does not appear to be actively maintained any more. It might be a good idea to move to a more modern package. For complex citation styles like this, I'd say `biblatex` is probably the best choice.

A switch to `biblatex` requires a few changes to your code and a change to your workflow, but should be fairly painless nowadays. See [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864), [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) as well as [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) for some background.

You may want to have a look at the `verbose` style family

- [`style=verbose,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/70-style-verbose-biber.pdf)
- [`style=verbose-ibid,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/71-style-verbose-ibid-biber.pdf)
- [`style=verbose-note,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/72-style-verbose-note-biber.pdf)
- [`style=verbose-inote,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/73-style-verbose-inote-biber.pdf)
- [`style=verbose-trad1,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/74-style-verbose-trad1-biber.pdf)
- [`style=verbose-trad2,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/75-style-verbose-trad2-biber.pdf)
- [`style=verbose-trad3,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/76-style-verbose-trad3-biber.pdf)

Once you've found the style that comes closest to what you want, it can be tweaked quite extensively. See [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) for a first overview.

`biblatex`'s citation commands accept up to two optional arguments. One for a prenote and one for a postnote.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[Siehe][180]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[Vgl.][12]{worman}
dolor \autocite[181]{sigfridsson}
sit \autocite[182]{sigfridsson}
amet \autocite[20]{nussbaum}
consectur \autocite[45]{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote citations using "a.a.O." and "Ebd." as well as "Siehe" und "Vgl."]